# Laravel Unit Test Illegal Offset Type

Tags: laravel

I'm currently trying to understand unit testing in Laravel and I'm trying to see if I can branch off from a tutorial I found by adding an option to have a `/posts` route that displays all of the posts in a grid but I've come across an error and I'm having trouble understanding where it's going wrong.

ViewABlogPostTest.php

```
public function testSeeAllPosts()
    {
        $response = $this->get("/posts");

        $response->assertStatus(200);
    }
```

When running it I get the following error:

1 ) Tests\Feature\ViewABlogPostTest::testSeeAllPosts
ErrorException: Illegal offset type

web.php Route:

```
Route::get('/posts', 'PostController@all');
```

PostController all function:

```
public function all(){
      $posts = Post::all();

      return view('all-posts')->with($posts, 'posts');
    }
```

all-posts.blade.php:

```
This page is supposed to show all of the posts in the db
@foreach($posts as $post)
<p>{{ $post->id }} | {{ $post->title }} | {{ $post->body }}</p>
@endforeach
```

I've tried to look into passing arrays into views and this should be how I do it but I don't understand what this error means and searching it doesn't make sense, did I do the post incorrectly? or is there another way I'm supposed to pass array data to the view?

Comment: So, what's in `ViewABlogPostTest::testSeeAllPosts()`?

Comment: Please add your test code - also: does the issue only occur while testing or also when opening the view directly?

Comment: sorry I forgot to add it since it didn't seem like a lot of code, just checking if it came back with a 200

Comment: and when I try to open that page it says it can't reach the page, error 500, checking the logs it says that `posts` doesn't exist

Comment: In your `PostController` can you try `->with('posts', $posts);` instead of `->with($posts, 'posts');` that might fix your `500` errors on web

Answer (score 0):

I think `view()->with()` takes `key` then `value`. Your code switches those arguments. Try this in your `PostController`

```php
public function all() {
    $posts = Post::all();
    return view('all-posts')->with('posts', $posts);
}
```

Comment: unfortunately doing that results in `[2020-08-06 15:38:54] local.ERROR: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42P01]: Undefined table: 7 ERROR:  relation "posts" does not exist
LINE 1: select * from "posts"`

Comment: Do you have `posts` table in your database? The `Post` model automatically tries to query `posts` table in db but you don't seem to have such table.

Comment: it does on a postgres db link I have, I don't understand why it's not working

Comment: It doesn't seem to me you have a correct DB connection. Try to query anything using tinker. I believe your test is failing because the `/posts` route is giving `500` or `PDOException`. Your first syntax was incorrect giving you `500`, the corrected one is working only it's not finding the database.

Comment: I've been able to push migrations though, I also haven't used tinker before, are there any good references for starting off?

Comment: Just to add, make sure you are using the `RefreshDatabase` trait in your test case.

Comment: In your terminal type `php artisan tinker` to enter tinker then in there type any php commands like `$posts = \App\Models\Post::all();` see if it queries successfully. See [tinker](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/artisan#tinker)